# Google Fit dataRead returns status TIMEOUT

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I am trying to get step data from Google Fit Api.  I am able to successfully connect to the Api, however when I try to retrieve data using the Fitness.HistoryApi.readData() function, it always returns status TIMEOUT and no data.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!  Code below

```
private void requestHistory() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    //Google Fit Client connection happens elswhere
    if (mClient.isConnected) {
        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(start, System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();


        DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        //HERE dataReadResult always has status TIMEOUT and no data
        if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
            //do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error in the stack trace? I'd guess the API call isn't authorized correctly.

Comment: No error in stack trace, just no data coming back from the read. I've requested the 'read activity' permission and I'm requesting Fitness.HistoryAPI with scope 'activity read' when I create the client connection

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Maybe it will help someone.  I was doing this inside of an AsyncTask, and for some reason that caused it to timeout.  Moving this logic outside of the AsyncTask's doInBackground method fixed the issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue but issue is not with AsyncTask but Service. Basically Ftiness API will always return timeout when called anywhere from 
a class extending Service class.

Comment: if move outside aysnctask , it will occur error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: await must not be called on the UI thread when time is greater than zero.