# Google fitness API returns TIMEOUT when activity is not visible

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I am currently experimenting with Google fitness API to get step count for the day.

Here is the code :

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        DailyTotalResult totalResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(mClient, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA).await(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        Log.d(TAG, "Timer TASK" + totalResult.toString());
    }
}
```

I have all the permissions and authorizations. I get following log when the activity is visible :

> Timer TASKDailyTotalResult{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS,
>   resolution=null}, dataPoint=DataSet{d:step_count.delta:gms:aggregated
>   [RawDataPoint{[12874]@1518402875448000000,
>   1518448273927981240}]}}

When the activity is not visible I get following as log :

> Timer TASKDailyTotalResult{status=Status{statusCode=TIMEOUT,
>   resolution=null}, dataPoint=DataSet{d:step_count.delta: []}}

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898766/google-fit-dataread-returns-status-timeout)? Could it be that the code was placed inside AsyncTask or maybe it was called anywhere from a class extending Service class as describe in the comment of this post?

Comment: Already seen that post. That comment related to service class is mine. No the above code is directly under TimerTask which gets activated from onCreate. Moreover I get perfectly fine data when activity is visible.